# Need a good quantity comparison of Geth/Cerberus/Reaper troops in silver/gold

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

So I like playing on silver and occasionally gold in Mass Effect 3 multiplayer, usually with random enemies. Of course each wave as it progresses has more difficult troops to fight but what I'm asking is when comparing Reapers, Cerberus and Geth, how many of what troops are being sent depending on who your playing and what wave.

I'm asking because it seems reapers send a multitude of banshees and brutes, which are armored and deadly troops. Cerberus has the Atlas, which is about the same level as banshees and brutes but not nearly as many are sent out as the reapers banshees and brutes. Same along the lines with the Geth and the Geth primes.

---

little update, I understand this question is incredibly difficult to get a decent answer for so i started a little research of my own. Havent tried gold yet but for silver i have done a Reaper and Cerberus match and on Wave 9 i see about 4 atlases and about 6 phantoms against cerberus and against the Reapers i tend to see 2 Banshees and 4 Brutes and 4 Ravangers. Trying to get how they decided what was equivalent to what.

Comment: They definitely send more Brutes and Ravagers than Atlases, in fact I think only one Atlas can be out at a time.

Comment: @ Ben Brocka Well i have seen 4 or more atlases out at a time in Gold difficulty. i did forget about the Ravagers thank you for mentioning them as well

Comment: Ah, I usually play on Bronze, so maybe that's just a limit on bronze

Comment: @ben brocka Atlas is not equivilent to Ravager, but Banshee. The Banshee is the biggest reaper unit and as such matches the atlas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a spreadsheet showing this [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/lv?key=0AmsYTS1wvgPwdENGMDBrbDB0YUdaOUVTTVlnYTdhX2c&rm=full#gid=1). Screenshots are below.
[image: Cerberus]
[image: Geth]
[image: Reaper]

Comment: o wow, did you make this?

Comment: excellent chart, pulling the data out of the .ini file makes a lot of sense.

Comment: I'm not entirely positive that it's accurate, since I haven't played MP. If someone could verify, that would be great.

Comment: it seems pretty accurate just at a quick glance

Comment: We got to wave 8 on gold last night. Ran into 4 Banshees. There was even 4 banshees a couple of waves before that but can't remember what wave. The reason i remember was because we killed them two and two with a rocket

Comment: The multiplayer component has probably been patched since I posted this.

Comment: This list definitely isn't accurate where rocket troopers and geth pyros are concerned. I've been soloing a few silver matches and I'm killing upwards of 5 pyros and at least 10 rocket troopers from wave 6 onwards. Same with hunters. There's way more in the game from about wave 4 than the list states. I'm not sure if they've upped the numbers since this was written, however, because I also notice that it doesn't contain enemies such as Geth Bombers and Dragoons or Collectors.

Comment: @LIzzie this answer is from just after launch and hasn't been updated.

Answer (score 2):

I'll list the different progression of troops here, though you might know this already.

**Geth**: Geth -> Rocket Trooper -> Hunter -> Pyro -> Prime

**Reapers**: Husk -> Cannibal -> Marauder -> Brute -> Ravager -> Banshee

**Cerberus**: Trooper -> Centurion -> Nemesis -> Guardian -> Engineer -> Atlas -> Phantom

The geth troops have much less variety to throw at you, so in Silver I've seen that they simply throw more enemies at you as opposed to Bronze.

With the Reapers, they scale up the speed at which you start to get different troops.  On bronze, I usually see Marauders at wave 2, Brutes at wave 4, few Ravagers at wave 6, and Banshee's start around wave 7 or 8.  But on silver, I see those numbers jump back at least a wave or two, and then they double the number on screen.  Bronze, I will see one brute before wave 6, then two after that.  On silver, those numbers are basically doubled.  I do see a reduction in Cannibal's, though, so maybe it offsets the numbers and increases the troop strength.

Cerberus was the same way with me on Silver.  About the same number of guys, but double the amount of harder ones.  I was seeing Phantoms at about wave 6 where on Bronze, I was seeing them around wave 8.

I'll try to pay attention next time I get into multiplayer and see if I can count the number of troops I kill to give you a better read-out.

Comment: Im basically looking for exact numbers i want to count them out but doing it by myself proves to be challenging. Never thought of phantoms being higher then atlases although your right you do see them later and i do hate seeming them near me haha.